# on page load call controller method using data from query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to retrieve query string data on page load using `javascript`?
Let me explain my sample project in steps::

1. I have a view page showing tabular data. On button press, it retrieves id of the row and calls javascript function.
2. This javascript function, `getDetails(id)` has to call another view page, say Application.cshtml.
3. I have to pass the value of id and a variable message to this view page `Application.cshtml`.
4. I am trying to pass this as query string.
5. Now in this view page Application.cshtml, I have to retrieve the value of `id` and call contoller method to show the details of the `id` on **page load**.
6. Is it possible to do using `javascript`?

   function getDetails(id)

   {

   ```
    var message = "testing";
    var id_ = id;
    window.location = "/FirmModels/Application/" + id_;
   ```

   }

My problem is how can I retrieve the value of id and call controller method on page load using javascript in Application.cshtml?

Comment: Please can anyone share solution to this, I am also in search for similar problem solution

Comment: I have noticed people are more drawn to bounties. If you can and need the answer really fast, make it a bounty

Comment: @DankyiAnnoKwaku Hope you are not one of those. If you know the solution, please can you reply. Thank You!!!

Comment: I am working on it. Give me a new minutes. Please vote up my answer and comments if it helps.

Comment: Please clarify, is it that you have the query string and just want to get the ID from it?

Comment: No, I have to retrieve ID from query string and call controller method on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear but as far as I understood this question you can do this in two ways.

Assuming that you have something like this in your JS file.

```
window.location = "/Controller/Application?id= " + id_;
```

In the first method, the View inside your Controller will look like this

```
public ActionResult Application()
    {
        string id= Request.QueryString["id"];
        //Do your operations here
        return View();
    }
```

The second way to do this to pass the id as a mandatory parameter to the view.

```
public ActionResult Application(string id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```